# Word choice for 'please' when begging?

Tags: word-choice

Japanese *shockingly* is really into politeness, and thus I've found a million different words for the English 'please'.

But I must ask, what would be the best word/phrase to use when begging. Like when a child asks 'Please daddy don't go!', what is the Japanese equivalent to the English's emphasising word 'please'?

Comment: Is the begging coquettish or desperate?

Comment: I was thinking more the kind you get when a child is forced to realise how little power they have when faced with a situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do need an equivalent, probably it's お願い (casual) or お願いします (politer), but I think Japanese small children use this far less often. To their parents, they would usually say [ねえ](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AD) (a general-purpose attention-drawer word similar to "Hey" or "Come on"), or simply repeat the "don't go" part.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one of the most used ways to say that.

> お願いだから
>   onegaidakara